# How to build an MSI using WIX, JAVA and MAVEN

Tags: java, maven, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to build an Msi from a java application which is using the spring and maven frameworks. From all the reading up i have done it would seem Wix is the best option. With some further research i started seeing mention of a Wix Maven plugin. The problem is following the websites and what i should place into the pom I don't get the Jar file being found.

has anyone succeded in this or know where to find the jar file?

Below is the Wix maven information.

```
  <plugin> 
    <groupId>npanday.plugin</groupId>  
    <artifactId>wix-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>${version}</version>  
    <configuration>  
      <sourceFiles>  
        <sourceFile>installer/Kiddo.wxs</sourceFile>  
      </sourceFiles>  
      <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>  
      <objectFiles>  
        <objectFile>target/Kiddo.wixobj</objectFile>  
      </objectFiles>  
      <outputFile>target/Kiddo.msi</outputFile>  
    </configuration>  
    <executions>  
      <execution>  
        <id>wix</id>  
        <goals>  
          <goal>candle</goal>  
          <goal>light</goal>  
        </goals>  
      </execution>  
    </executions>  
  </plugin>  


<dependency>  
        <groupId>org.apache.npanday.plugins</groupId>  
        <artifactId>wix-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>1.4.0-incubating</version>  
</dependency>
```

these are wrapped with the additional maven tags  and

Nathan

Comment: the wix files are Kiddo,Kiddo.heat.xsl and Kiddo.wxs

Comment: http://incubator.apache.org/npanday/docs/1.2/plugins/wix-maven-plugin/project-reports.html this is the maven plugin I had found for Wix

Comment: Which jar file? You haven't been very clear what's missing or what error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

Still a work in progress, but you might also be interested in a more fully featured WiX maven lifecycle.  There is more than just candle and light.
[com.github.wix-maven:wix-maven-plugin](http://wix-maven.github.io/wix-maven-plugin)
sourced from [github](https://github.com/wix-maven/wix-maven-plugin)